# Using exponential family to find the derivate of the partition function

Tags: statistics, exponential-function, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution, maximum-likelihood

Distributions that follow the exponential family have the following form
\begin{equation}
p(x) = h(x)\exp \left[\theta^T T(x) - H(\theta)\right]
\end{equation}
and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}H(\theta) = \mathbb E_p[T(X)]$.

I have the following function
\begin{equation}
H(\theta) = \log \int_z \exp \left[\log P(y|z) - \frac{z^2}{2v} + \frac{mz}{2v}\right]
\end{equation}

I want to find $\frac{\partial}{\partial m}H(\theta)$. For this define $T(z) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & z/v & z^2 \end{bmatrix}^T$ and $\theta = \begin{bmatrix} \log P(y|z) & m & -1/2v \end{bmatrix}^T$. Is it correct that $\frac{\partial}{\partial m}H(\theta) = \mathbb E[T_2(z)|\theta] = \mathbb E[\frac{z}{v}|\theta]$?

Comment: Reading about exponential family with [vector parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Vector_parameter) I find your notation using those expectations $\mathbb E$ extremely confusing. Is that $\theta$ not a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ ? What is $\int\limits_z$ and over which variable to you integrate ?

Comment: $\int_z  f(z) = \int f(z)$ I noticed that my $T(z), \theta$ are probably wrong, how would you choose them

Comment: oh I forgot $dz$ at the end

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how I would choose $T(z)$ and $\theta$ . Questions need details and clarity to be answerable .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like
$$
H(\theta) = \log \int \exp \left[\log P(y|z) - \frac{z^2}{2v} + \frac{mz}{2v}\right]dz
$$
where the integration is over a range in which $z$ is defined. Let's write this more shortly as
$$
H(\theta) = \log G(\theta)
$$
with an obvious definition of $G(\theta)$.
The answer to your question is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial m}H(\theta)&=\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial m}G(\theta)}{G(\theta)}\,.
\end{align}
Since
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial m}G(\theta)&=\int\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\exp \left[\log P(y|z) - \frac{z^2}{2v} + \frac{mz}{2v}\right]dz\\
&=G(\theta)\int \frac{z}{2v}dz
\end{align}
we get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial m}H(\theta)=\int \frac{z}{2v}dz.
$$

Comment: thanks alot, I see now that I made it much more complicated than necessary